# Manual language selection in localization

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization

I am working on internationalisation in my app. It works on both language english and turkish...

I made two differnt scheme for run in different-different language.

[image: OTOGAR is For English And TurkishOTOGAR work for turkish language]

But I want to change language on click event of button like[image: User can slect the language from here]

so how can I select the language scheme on the click event of button? means when user press "turkish" button my app must be display in turkish language and when user press "English" button app must be display in English language.

Comment: Build schemes are for development, they have nothing to do with the applications package, hence you can't switch them at runtime. If you want to change languages on the fly, you need to to that manually in code.

Comment: Please consider not using a language picker inside your app; this will be very confusing to customers who have their iOS device set to a particular language.

Comment: but how can i do this??@CihanTek

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the language of you app using NSLocalization and the way you want. NSLocalization is always according to user device specification. You can not change it.

You have to re-write NSLocalization.